# Error in using Juju on local machine

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I invoked the following commands on my Ubuntu 12.04 server:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install juju-core
sudo apt-get install juju-local linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-haeders-generic-lts-raring
juju init
juju switch local
sudo juju bootstrap
```

The last command generated an error message:

```
error: 503 503 Service Unavailable
```

Is there anyone who could help me solve this problem?

Note: I used Ubuntu 12.04 Server running on a VM with VMWare player. I also have to use internet proxy (yes, I have defined my proxy server in environment variable: http_proxy and https_proxy).

Comment: CMIIW: it seems that Juju does not allow us to connect to Juju/Charm store via web proxy.